# problem with a simple program (check a number is an even number or odd number using javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am writing a very simple program in JavaScript to check a number is an odd number or even number. and here is my code.

```
  function run(number) {
    var result;
    if(number % 2 == 0) {
      result == 'even';
    }
    else {
      result == 'odd';
    }
    return result;
  }
```

As you can see, very easy to understand, right? I have the variable number and check it. I thought that my algorithm is correct.
But the program still does not run.

Could you please show me why the program has the problem ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: do you call that function? also remove one '=' from `result ==` to assign a value.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is (loose) comparison. (By the way: "very easy to understand, right?" << it would be even easier to understand if it were properly indented!)

Comment: You could also try the [is-odd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-odd) package :)

Answer (score 0):

Two things here

```js
function run(number) {
    var result;
    if (number % 2 == 0) 
        result = 'even';
    else 
        result = 'odd';
    
    return result;
}

const val = run(11);
console.log(val);
```

You should be using `=` (assignment operator) as you're assigning value to a variable and not comparing them (== or === are called [comparison operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)).

And make sure you actually call the function

Comment: Thank you very much. just by using your comment I could solved my problem now.

Comment: no problem, please consider marking the answer as correct if it helped you :D

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers & comments already point out, `==` is not storing the result but instead, an operator to compare two variables. One equal sign would do the job. Additionally, I'm suggesting the shorthand version (recommended once you understood what went wrong in the first place):

```js
function run(number) {
  return (number % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
}
console.log(run(5))
console.log(run(6))
```

Comment: You don't need the `== 0` here and if you compare things it's better to use `===`